# How to check if any URLs within my website contain specific Google Analytics UTM codes?

Tags: google-analytics, coldfusion

The website I manage uses Google Analytics to track URLs. Recently I found out that some of the URLs contain UTM codes and should not. I need some way of determining whether or not URLs that contain the following UTM codes `utm_source=redirect` or `utm_source=redirectfolder` are currently on the website and being redirected within the same website. If so, I will need to remove the UTM codes on those URLs, because Google Analytics automatically tracks URLs that redirect within the same domain. So it does not require UTM codes (and this actually hurts the analytics).

My apologies if I sound a little broken here, I am still trying to understand it all myself, as I am a new graduate with a CS degree and I am now the only web developer. I am not asking for anyone to write this for me, just if I could be pointed in the right direction to writing a ColdFusion script that may help with this.

Comment: You want to pull Google Analytics data? To see what is going on with URLS? Is this correct? Like, bring it down to a local machine and do some checking (using Coldfusion). The answer is: It can be done. If I understand you right. But it is NOT easy.

Comment: @FrankTudor He does not want to pull GA data, he wants to clear wrong query parameters from the links within a web page (i.e. cleaning up the source code of the page) as UTM parameters within the page obscure the original traffic source.

Comment: @EikePierstorff That is exactly right. Thank you for clarifying that. Sorry if I was not clear enough Frank Tudor.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Phew...What you are saying is easier to do....I have a solution.

Comment: @FrankTudor I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide. Like I said, I am not trying to pawn work off on anyone, I just need to be pointed in the right direction. I am going through sort of "thrown into the fire" sort of training since I don't really have anyone else I can turn to for training.

Comment: @Default42 You'll be fine. This is a great little mini-project (that has an end). And if you have an end goal you can do it... :) Just break it into chunks. Get a cfdirectory listing to output to a page...That would be step one.

Comment: @Default42 Also, I'll see if I have some sample code to get you started...but I have not had to do anything like this in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand correctly your codebase is riddled with problematic URLS. To clean up the URLs programmatically you'll need to do a couple of things up front.

1. Identify the querystring parameter variable/value pair that needs to be
   eliminated.
2. Create a worker file to access all your `.cfm` and `.cfc` files (of interest).
3. Create a loop that goes through the directories and reads, edits and saves your files (be careful here not to go crazy, maybe do not set to overwrite existing files (like make unique, unless you are sure).
4. Create a find/replace function or regex expression to target and remove your troublesome parameters
5. Save your file and move on in the loop.

**OR:**

You can use and IDE like dreamweaver or sublimetext to locate these via a regex search and spot check and remove.

I would selectively remove the URL parameters, but if you have so many pages that it makes no sense, then programmatic removal would be the way to go.

You will be using `cfdirectory`, `cffile`, `rematch()` (and create an array and rebuild) or find/replace `replaceNoCase()`

Your cfdirectory call will return a variable and like a query you will spin through it like you do with a normal query and `cfoutput`.

Pull one or two files out of your repo to create your code with until you are confortable. I would code in exit strategies (fail gracefully) like adding a locatable comments to the change spot so you can check it later manually, or escape out if a file won't write and many other try/catch opportunities.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Frank, thank you for taking the time to put this together. This at least gets me moving in the right direction. I am actually going the more simpler route. With the current situation, I am not going to programmatically remove/replace the URLs. I am just looking to create some file that will output the URL (that contains the specific UTM Google Analytics codes) and the area where that URL exists The website I manage is organized by page IDs so I imagine a file to output the URL and page ID would be all I need.